# Hints needed in expectation calculation

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation

I'm currently at a loss when calculating an expectation from a joint density function. This function is: $f_{XY}(x,y)=xe^{-10xy}(0.9)^{x-1}
, y > 0, x \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ and I'm required to do $E(E(XY|Y))$.

I've done $E(XY)$ calculation straightforward and it's $\frac{1}{10}$ (since it can be shown that there's an exponential (-10x) and geometric (0.1) nuclei and you can operate both of them in the expectation) but I'm having problems doing the other route.

For $E(E(XY|Y))$ calculation I understand I have to calculate $\int{Y E(X|Y) f_{Y}(y)}dy$. I've  calculated the marginal density function for Y which is $\frac{e^{-10y}}{(1-0.9e^{-10y})^{2}}$ and $E(X|Y)$ as $\frac{1+0.9e^{-10y}}{1-0.9e^{-10y}}$. After this I've replaced this in $E(E(XY|Y))$ but I can't seem to get $\frac{1}{10}$. Can I get a hint or am I messing up the calculations of $f_{Y}(y)$ and $Y E(X|Y)$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add the self study tag.

Comment: Alright, I added it.

Comment: You do not have a joint _density_ function in the usual sense of the world since $X$ takes on positive integer values only, and is a _discrete_ random variable. Rather, what you have is a collection of _line_ densities.

Comment: You shouldn't write $f_y(y)$ where you mean $f_Y(y)$ or $f_{xy}(x,y)$ where you mean $f_{X,Y}(x,y).$ When you don't attend to such distinctions you can't understand something like $\Pr(X\le x)$ or $f_X(3). \qquad$

Comment: Same comment on notation:$$\int{Y E(X|Y) f_{y}(y)}dy$$should be$$\int yE(X|Y=y)  f_{Y}(y)dy$$

Comment: Thank you for your feedback all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments about your notation. You should use capital letters when referring to RVs and lowercase when referring to specific values. Also, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is not a joint density as Dilip says, however correct use of summation and integrals rids of the nomenclature. Apart from that, Your $E[X|Y]$ and $f_Y(y)$ are correct, which leaves you with the final integral as below:
$$E[XY]=\int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-10y}\frac{1+0.9e^{-10y}}{(1-0.9e^{-10y})^3}dy$$

You can verify that this integral is indeed $1/10$ via the following code line in Wolfram Alpha:

```
`integrate y*e^{-10y} *(1+0.9*e^{-10y})/(1-0.9*e^{-10y})^3 from y=0 to \infty`
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback. It's a big relief to see it's \frac{1}{10}. I'll try to solve it on pencil now but I now know I'm on the right track.